# Manipulating dynamic arrays in C

Tags: c, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to solve [StringMerge (PP0504B)](http://pl.spoj.com/problems/PP0504B/) problem from SPOJ (PL). Basically the problem is to write a function `string_merge(char *a, char *b)` that returns a pointer to an char array with string created from char arrays with subsequent chars chosen alternately (length of the array is the length of the shorter array provided as an argument).

The program I've created works well with test cases but it fails when I post it to SPOJ's judge. I'm posting my code here, as I believe it the problem is related to memory allocation (I'm still learning this part of C) - could you take a look at my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define T_SIZE 1001

char* string_merge(char *a, char *b);

char* string_merge(char *a, char *b) {
    int alen = strlen(a); int blen = strlen(b);
    int len  = (alen <= blen) ? alen : blen;
    int i,j;

    char *new_array = malloc (sizeof (char) * (len));
    new_array[len] = '\0';
    for(j=0,i=0;i<len;i++) {
            new_array[j++] = a[i];
            new_array[j++] = b[i];
    }
    return new_array;
}

int main() {
    int n,c; scanf("%d", &n);
    char word_a[T_SIZE];
    char word_b[T_SIZE];
    while(n--) {
        scanf("%s %s", word_a, word_b);
        char *x = string_merge(word_a, word_b);
        printf("%s",x);
        printf("\n");
        memset(word_a, 0, T_SIZE);
        memset(word_b, 0, T_SIZE);
        memset(x,0,T_SIZE);
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Note: I'm compiling it with `-std=c99` flag.

Comment: Try it with `ElectricFence` or `valgrind`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Off-by-one.

```
char *new_array = malloc (sizeof (char) * (len));
new_array[len] = '\0';
```

You're writing past the bounds of `new_array`. You must allocate space for `len + 1` bytes:

```
char *new_array = malloc(len + 1);
```

Also, `sizeof(char)` is always 1, so spelling it out is superfluous, so are the parenthesis around `len`.

***Woot, further errors!***

So then you keep going and increment `j` twice within each iteration of the `for` loop. So essentially you end up writing (approximately) twice as many characters as you allocated space for.

Also, you're leaking memory by not `free()`ing the return value of `string_merge()` after use.

Furthermore, I don't see what the `memset`s are for, also I suggest you use `fgets()` and `strtok_r()` for getting the two words instead of `scanf()` (which doesn't do what you think it does).

Comment: Thanks, one more question - I've found `malloc (sizeof (char) * len)` somewhere on SO, are there any conditions when it can be useful?

Comment: @REACHUS No, not really. A lot of people misuse `sizeof()` (especially when combined with `malloc()`).

Answer (score 0):

```
char *new_array = malloc (sizeof (char) * (len*2 + 1));
new_array[len*2] = '\0';
```